# FabricJS: bug with opacity of circles in a group?

Tags: javascript, canvas, opacity, fabricjs

When I add a circle with an opacity lower than 1 to a group, its opacity becomes actually lower than the specified value. This does not happen if I don't specify opacity (i.e., opacity = 1). It also doesn't happen with a rectangle.

Here is the code to reproduce this issue:

## HTML

```
<canvas id="stage" width="400" height="300">
```

## JavaScript

```
var OPACITY = 0.65;
var FILL = '#fff';

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('stage', {
    backgroundColor: '#222'
});

/**
 * Rectangles
 * both appear to have the same color
 */
var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    fill: FILL,
    opacity: OPACITY,
    left: 60,
    top: 60
});
canvas.add(rect1);

var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    fill: FILL
    opacity: OPACITY,
});
var rect2Group = new fabric.Group([rect2], {
    left: 120,
    top: 60
});
canvas.add(rect2Group);

/**
 * Circles
 * the second circle is darker
 */
var circle1 = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 20,
    fill: FILL,
    opacity: OPACITY,
    left: 60,
    top: 120
});
canvas.add(circle1);

var circle2 = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 20,
    fill: FILL,
    opacity: OPACITY,
});
var circle2Group = new fabric.Group([circle2], {
    left: 120,
    top: 120
});
canvas.add(circle2Group);
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYhRV/).

If you run it, you can see that the second circle is darker than the first one, meaning that its opacity is lower.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? (Could be reproduced in 1.2.0 and 1.3.0.)

Comment: For now, my workaround is to set the `FILL = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65)'` and not use OPACITY at all. This way both circles (i.e, with and without a group) look identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely because of [this line](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/src/shapes/circle.class.js#L95-L96) in `fabric.Circle`:

```
// multiply by currently set alpha
// (the one that was set by path group where this object is contained, for example)
ctx.globalAlpha = this.group ? (ctx.globalAlpha * this.opacity) : this.opacity;
```

This has to do with circles being part of SVG group, IIRC.

In any case, it's definitely a bug — the opacity shouldn't be multiplied in your case. We need to have a better check.

Please file an issue on github.

Comment: Thanks kangax for your feedback. [Issue](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/901) has been filed.